# how can i replace my own "Phone Ringing" screen instead of android's default one?

Tags: android, android-service, phone-state-listener

I did some googling but couldnt find a clear answer for my question.

I have an activity that need's to be launched when the phone starts to ringing (receives a phone call)- instead of androids default screen .

[image]

I know I must set a receiver in Manifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<receiver android:name=".ServiceReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

and create a receiver class :

```html
public class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {

    public static Boolean phoneRinging = false;

    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

        switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                Log.e("DEBUG", "IDLE");
                phoneRinging = false;
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                Log.e("DEBUG", "OFFHOOK");
                phoneRinging = false;
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                //Intent intent=new Intent(getClass().)
                Log.e("DEBUG", "RINGING");
                phoneRinging = true;

                break;
        }
    }

}

class ServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    TelephonyManager telephony;
    Intent in;
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        MyPhoneStateListener phoneListener = new MyPhoneStateListener();
        telephony = (TelephonyManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        telephony.listen(phoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
   
    }
}
```

now I can grab "RINGING" in my logcat correctly but how can I start my custom activity or what is the preferred way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found an answer and i'm going to share that with you.

first there is nothing to do with `onCallStateChanged` portion .
so i must call target activity in `onReceive` inside BroadcastReceiver class :

```js
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            String state = extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                Intent intent1=new Intent(context, Ringing.class);
                intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                context.startActivity(intent1);
              
            }
        }
    }
```